# Implementing API key communication

Tags: php, api, rest, backbone.js

I'm designing a client-server communication just for learning purposes for now.

On the server's side is php restful server and on the client's backbone js app.

The basic idea:

- after successful login, server will generate unique API key, store it into DB and it will expire after some time of account inactivity
- client will obtain this key and user id, save it in secure cookie and use it with every request
- if keys are a match, server will process the request
- all communication is on https

Is this process safe or what would you suggest?

And I really dont want to go with Oauth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While ago, I've create a reference for API token based authorization, located [here](https://github.com/alexanderbeletsky/backbone-express-spa#authorization-cors).

Something I do in one of the projects.

1. User signups, and API key is being generated.
2. User saves the API key to localstore or secured cookie.
3. To access API he has to exchange API key to Access Token. He sends request to endpoint and is userId and apiKey matches, HMAC-bases access token is issued.
4. All API requests require access token passed either by `access_token` query parameter or `token` value in cookie.

All that have to work on SSL.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I've proposed. Thanks for HMAC-based token generation.